# How to use concepts in if statement

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, c++-concepts

I have a concept which checks whether a type is iterable or not

```cpp
template<typename T>
concept Iterable = requires(T t) {
    t.begin();
};
```

I cannot use it in a template due to problems with overloading, so I'd like to do something similar to the following:

```cpp
template<typename T>
void universal_function(T x) {
    if (x is Iterable)
        // something which works with iterables
    else if (x is Printable)
       // another thing
    else
       // third thing
}
```

Comment: @Incomputable I think you're switching up `if consteval` with `if constexpr`, `consteval` doesn't seem relevant here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Concept instantiations are boolean values, so they can be used in `if` statements. You will need to use `if constexpr` to achieve the desired behavior, as it will allow for branches containing code that would be invalid in a different branch:

```cpp
if constexpr (Iterable<T>) {
    // ...
} else if constexpr (Printable<T>) {
    // ...
} else {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I think, what OP was missing here was not the `if constexpr` feature per se, but the fact that concepts can be used in boolean expressions directly. What `constexpr` provides is the ability to write code in one branch that would be invalid in another, which you can't do with a regular `if`.

Comment: @SU3 Very true! I've edited my answer to address this :)

Comment: They don't just implicitly convert to bool, they _are_ bool.

Answer (score 2):

You can directly write the `requires` clause inside the `if` to determine the validity of the expression, something like this

```
template<typename T>
void universal_function(T x) {
    if constepxr (requires {  x.begin(); }) {
        // something which works with iterables
    }
    else if constepxr (requires {  std::cout << x; }) {
       // another thing
    }
    else {
       // third thing
    }
}
```

But it seems that only detecting whether `x.begin()` is well-formed is not enough for iterable types, the standard library already has a `concept` for this, namely [`std::ranges::range`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/range):

```
if constepxr (std::ranges::range<T>) {
   // something which works with iterables
}
```

Comment: Pretty cool feature that I didn't know about, but you're missing bodies for the first two `if`s ;)